# Type hint for class with __dict__ method

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a class that can be instantiated from a dataclass.

```
class Asd:
    @classmethod
    def from_dataclass(cls, dataclass):
        return cls(**dataclass.__dict__)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
```

In principle I could pass to `from_dataclass` any class with a `__dict__` method, and I would like the type hint to reflect this.

What I have done is to create my protocol.

```
from typing import Protocol

class HasDict(Protocol):
    def __dict__(self):
        ...

class Asd:
    @classmethod
    def from_dataclass(cls, dataclass: HasDict):
        return cls(**dataclass.__dict__)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
```

I wonder if I'm reinventing the wheel or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: "Being" a dataclass is more a statement of how the class was defined, rather than a description of the resulting class's structure. *Most* classes have a `__dict__`, and whether an arbitrary class has the necessary attributes to instantiate `cls` is something that makes this class method almost too broad to be useful.

Comment: FYI there is `from dataclasses import asdict` `d = asdict(mydataclass)` ... this will recursively dict-ify any child dataclasses in fields of the parent

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the best thing is either to restrict `from_dataclass` so that it really only expects a dataclass and return `asdict(dataclass)`, or to remove it altogether and expect the user to know that they can convert a dataclass to a dict and then pass it to the regular `__init__`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the type of `cls` itself is the protocol that the `dataclass` argument would need to adhere to.

Comment: I think it might make more sense to be specific here. I am sure your class `Asd` actually has a useful and descriptive constructor signature with named parameters (not just `**kwargs`). I would dynamically look up attributes with the same names on the object passed to `from_dataclass` (or whatever you want to call it) and pass those as arguments to the constructor. Then your protocol can be defined in terms of those (public) attributes. Otherwise I agree with @chepner, this is so broad, it is basically useless.

Comment: (If `Asd` does *not* have named parameters, it really should. `**kwargs` is primarily meant to accept arbitrary arguments intended to be passed on to some *other* function, not those consumed by `Add` itself. Capturing types in that case is what `ParamSpec` is for.)

Comment: Indeed, `Asd` has named parameters actually. In reality it's not even called `Asd` in real life as you might have guessed XD. Thanks for the comments I will try to collect them in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you added some context in your comments, I'll address the "bigger picture".

#### Problem

We have a class with a *specific* constructor and want to write a special method `from_obj` to instantiate it from **any object** that has attributes that match the non-optional parameters of our constructor.

#### Solution

Define a protocol that has attributes with the same names **and** types as the non-optional parameters of our constructor. Then explicitly pass those attributes as the corresponding arguments to the constructor inside `from_obj`.

#### Example

To make this a bit more interesting, let's include the possibility of positional-only as well as optional parameters in our constructor. Say we have a class `Foo` with the following `__init__` signature:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int, /, y: str, z: bool = True) -> None: ...
```

Both `x` and `y` are required, `x` is positional only, and `z` has a default, thus is not required for instantiation.

The protocol should reflect the **bare minimum** needed to instantiate our `Foo`, so it will look like this:

```py
class FooCompatible(Protocol):
    x: int
    y: str
```

In our `from_obj` method we can now annotate the parameter with that protocol and do some additional steps to accommodate the different parameter categories. Here is a simple example for a working `Foo` class and the setup I would suggest:

```py
from typing import Protocol
from typing_extensions import Self


class FooCompatible(Protocol):
    x: int
    y: str


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int, /, y: str, z: bool = True) -> None:
        self.spam = x * y.upper()
        self.not_z = not z

    @classmethod
    def from_obj(cls, obj: FooCompatible) -> Self:
        try:
            optional_kwargs = {"z": getattr(obj, "z")}
        except AttributeError:
            optional_kwargs = {}
        return cls(obj.x, y=obj.y, **optional_kwargs)
```

Usage:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
# ... import Foo


@dataclass
class Bar:
    x: int
    y: str
    z: bool


@dataclass
class Baz:
    x: int
    y: str


foo1 = Foo.from_obj(Bar(3, "a", False))
print(foo1.spam, foo1.not_z)  # AAA True


foo2 = Foo.from_obj(Baz(2, "b"))
print(foo2.spam, foo2.not_z)  # BB False
```

This passes `mypy --strict` without errors. If we for example changed `Baz.y` to be a `float`, then Mypy would immediately complain that the argument to `from_obj` has the wrong type.

Note that I only used dataclasses here for *convenience*. The `from_obj` method works with *any* class that is `FooCompatible`.

Of course, if the number of optional parameters the constructor has increases, the dynamic attribute access can become unwieldy, if you want to check for each of those individually. But one of the core tenets of Python has always been [*"explicit is better than implicit"*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/), so I would still suggest going the named route and *not* just grab the entire `__dict__`.